# Summation of Stirling numbers of second kind

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, stirling-numbers

Evaluate: 
\begin{equation}
n^{n-\ell} \cdot \sum\limits_{k=1}^\ell \dbinom{n}{k} k! \begin{Bmatrix} \ell \\ k \end{Bmatrix} 
\end{equation}

I used my primitive math skills along with the some formulas given in "Close Encounters with the Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind" by KHRISTO N. BOYADZHIEV to simplify the above equation to $n^n$. **Am I correct?**

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. Showing your work will help us to correct the mistakes, if there are any.

Comment: See the answers here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3076215/summation-of-binomial-coefficients-stirling-numbers-of-the-second-kind/3076350#3076350 ... Send me a message if you need more help.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Perfect, many thanks!! Can you please give me some reference to read more about the relation that you mentioned in your answer, namely $k! \begin{Bmatrix} n\\ k \end{Bmatrix} = n! [x^n]:(e^x -1)^k$?

Comment: $5^{th}$ formula here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Generating_functions and also look at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html ... the first two that come up when you google @Stirling numbers of the second knid.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit From your answer, I wondered what squaring of the Stirling number in the given expression leads to? I asked that question 3 days back and have been working on it myself since then; but to no avail. Link to my question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3081960.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're familiar with combinatorics, this being equal to $n^n$ means it counts functions $f:[n]\to[n]$ ($[n]$ denoting the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, since each of the $n$ elements in the domain have $n$ choices of image in the codomain.

I'll give you the idea of a proof and let you fill in the details. The given expression counts functions from $[n]$ to $[n]$ with some fixed subset $S$ of size $\ell$ of $[n]$. The term $n^{n-\ell}$ counts functions from $[n]-S$ to $[n]$, since each of the $n-\ell$ elements in the domain have $n$ choices o image in the codomain. The remaining sum $\sum_{k=1}^\ell \binom{n}{k}k! \begin{Bmatrix} \ell \\ k \end{Bmatrix}$ determines the image of $S$, where each $k$ corresponds to a possible size of $f(S)$. In other words, for each $k$, $\binom{n}{k}k! \begin{Bmatrix} \ell \\ k \end{Bmatrix}$ counts the number of functions $f:S\to [n]$ where $|f(S)|=k$.

The only other major fact you need is that $k! \begin{Bmatrix} \ell \\ k \end{Bmatrix}$ counts surjections $f:[\ell]\to[k]$. The Stirling number of the second kind counts partitions of $[\ell]$ into $k$ parts. There are $k!$ ways to associate each block with an element of $[k]$, creating a surjection from $[\ell]$ onto $[k]$.